# How to get the width of a react element

Tags: reactjs

Im trying to create a range input that displays a tooltip right above the slider thumb.

I went through some vanilla JS examples online and it seems that I need to have the width of the element to acomplish that.

So I was just wondering how to get the elements width?

Pretty much the equivalent of the JQuery method `$(element).width()`

Comment: In 2020, I highly recommend using react-use's useMeasure() instead. It returns width, height, x position, y position, and more.

Answer (score 143):

```
    class MyComponent extends Component {
      constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.myInput = React.createRef()
      }

      componentDidMount () {
        console.log(this.myInput.current.offsetWidth)
      }

      render () {
        return (
        // new way - as of React@16.3
        <div ref={this.myInput}>some elem</div>
        // legacy way
        // <div ref={(ref) => this.myInput = ref}>some elem</div>
        )
      }
    }
```

Comment: I just wanna say that apparently *this* way of creating refs is also deprecated now. (Now you create a ref in the constructor with `React.createRef()`)

Comment: @aaaidan Just checked the docs. Callback refs aren't deprecated. Sometimes you need them when you don't want to override the ref on a cloned element.

Comment: What id you want to get the width of Div element which is a React element not a native html element?

Comment: Thanks for maintaining the "legacy" way.

Answer (score 121):

With [hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html):

```
const MyComponent = () => {
  const ref = useRef(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('width', ref.current ? ref.current.offsetWidth : 0);
  }, [ref.current]);
  return <div ref={ref}>Hello</div>;
};
```

Comment: Instead of using both `useRef` and `useEffect` you can simply use a callback ref in the example above.

Comment: But it doesn't get updated when any resize happens, just when your ref.current changes

Comment: That works perfect. Also, with Typescript just add `const ref = useRef<HTMLHeadingElement>(null);`

Comment: Eslint says: React Hook useEffect has an unnecessary dependency: 'ref.current'. Either exclude it or remove the dependency array. Mutable values like 'ref.current' aren't valid dependencies because mutating them doesn't re-render the component.

Comment: I would switch to `useLayoutEffect`, and either skip the `, [ref.current]` entirely (to have it update every render), or add a `ResizeObserver` or something to update on resize.

Comment: "useLayoutEffect can hurt performance. Prefer useEffect when possible."  

See: 
https://react.dev/reference/react/useLayoutEffect

Answer (score 62):

This is basically Marco Antônio's answer for a React custom hook, but modified to set the dimensions initially and not only after a resize.

```
export const useContainerDimensions = myRef => {
  const [dimensions, setDimensions] = useState({ width: 0, height: 0 })

  useEffect(() => {
    const getDimensions = () => ({
      width: myRef.current.offsetWidth,
      height: myRef.current.offsetHeight
    })

    const handleResize = () => {
      setDimensions(getDimensions())
    }

    if (myRef.current) {
      setDimensions(getDimensions())
    }

    window.addEventListener("resize", handleResize)

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("resize", handleResize)
    }
  }, [myRef])

  return dimensions;
};
```

Used in the same way:

```
const MyComponent = () => {
  const componentRef = useRef()
  const { width, height } = useContainerDimensions(componentRef)

  return (
    <div ref={componentRef}>
      <p>width: {width}px</p>
      <p>height: {height}px</p>
    <div/>
  )
}
```

Comment: How does this even work for anybody? myRef in the useEffect's second parameter is the same (with 'current' being null in first render) and changes, but the useEffect is not being called again because the myRef actually didn't change.

Answer (score 48):

Actually, would be better to isolate this resize logic in a **custom hook**. You can create a custom hook like this:

```
const useResize = (myRef) => {
  const [width, setWidth] = useState(0)
  const [height, setHeight] = useState(0)
  
  const handleResize = useCallback(() => {
      setWidth(myRef.current.offsetWidth)
      setHeight(myRef.current.offsetHeight)
  }, [myRef])

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('load', handleResize)
    window.addEventListener('resize', handleResize)

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('load', handleResize)
      window.removeEventListener('resize', handleResize)
    }
  }, [myRef, handleResize])

  return { width, height }
}
```

and then you can use it like:

```
const MyComponent = () => {
  const componentRef = useRef()
  const { width, height } = useResize(componentRef)

  return (
    <div ref={componentRef }>
      <p>width: {width}px</p>
      <p>height: {height}px</p>
    <div/>
  )
}
```

Comment: You have to attach the resize event listener to the window I think: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/resize_event

Comment: `handleResize()` on the EventListeners or else useResize will return `{ 0, 0}`

Comment: Doesn't return the initial size.  I.e. only works after a resize.  To fix `useResize` needs to include `if (myRef.current) {<setWidth SetHeight etc,>)

Comment: For info, with the `addEventListener('load', ..)`it works for the initial size.

Comment: How does this even work for anybody? myRef in the useEffect's second parameter is the same (with 'current' being null in first render) and changes, but the useEffect is not being called again because the myRef actually didn't change..

Answer (score 18):

A simple and up to date solution is to use the React React [useRef](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref) hook that stores a reference to the component/element, combined with a [useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect) hook, which fires at component renders.

```js
import React, {useState, useEffect, useRef} from 'react';

export default App = () => {
  const [width, setWidth] = useState(0);
  const elementRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    setWidth(elementRef.current.getBoundingClientRect().width);
  }, []); //empty dependency array so it only runs once at render

  return (
    <div ref={elementRef}>
      {width}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: I get  columnRef.current.getBoundingRect is not a function

Comment: that means for some reason, the ref has not been bounded to the element at first render. An easy fix for that is to add `if (!ref.current) return;` before you're using the ref and also add ref to the dependency array so it'll look like `[ref]` instead of an empty one

Comment: it isn't getBoundingRect, it's getBoundingClientRect()

Answer (score 15):

Here is a TypeScript version of [@meseern's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60978633/3581829) that avoids unnecessary assignments on re-render:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

export function useContainerDimensions(myRef: React.RefObject<any>) {
  const [dimensions, setDimensions] = useState({ width: 0, height: 0 });

  useEffect(() => {
    const getDimensions = () => ({
      width: (myRef && myRef.current.offsetWidth) || 0,
      height: (myRef && myRef.current.offsetHeight) || 0,
    });

    const handleResize = () => {
      setDimensions(getDimensions());
    };

    if (myRef.current) {
      setDimensions(getDimensions());
    }

    window.addEventListener('resize', handleResize);

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('resize', handleResize);
    };
  }, [myRef]);

  return dimensions;
}
```

Comment: hi! what if it's a controlled component?

Answer (score 14):

**React 18.x in 2023**

For good reasons, React 18 changes how `useEffect` works. It's valid to run a piece of initialization code just once for a component, but read [*You might not need an effect*](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/you-might-not-need-an-effect) before reaching for `useEffect`. To get an element's dimensions, we can use the new `useSyncExternalStore` hook -

```js
// useDimensions.js

import { useMemo, useSyncExternalStore } from "react"

function subscribe(callback) {
  window.addEventListener("resize", callback)
  return () => {
    window.removeEventListener("resize", callback)
  }
}

function useDimensions(ref) {
  const dimensions = useSyncExternalStore(
    subscribe,
    () => JSON.stringify({
      width: ref.current?.offsetWidth ?? 0, // 0 is default width
      height: ref.current?.offsetHeight ?? 0, // 0 is default height
    })
  )
  return useMemo(() => JSON.parse(dimensions), [dimensions])
}

export { useDimensions }
```

You can use it like this -

```js
function MyComponent() {
  const ref = useRef(null)
  const {width, height} = useDimensions(ref)
  return <div ref={ref}>
    The dimensions of this div is {width} x {height}
  </div>
}
```

**why JSON.stringify?**

`useSyncExternalStore` expects the `getSnapshot` function to return a *cached* value, otherwise it will cause infinite re-renders.

```js
{width: 300, height: 200} === {width: 300, height: 200}
// => false ❌
```

`JSON.stringify` converts the object to a string so equality can be established -

```
'{"width":300,"height":200}' === '{"width":300,"height":200}'
// => true ✅
```

Finally, the `useMemo` hook ensures that the same dimensions object will be returned in subsequent renders. When the `dimensions` string changes, the memo is updated and the component using `useDimensions` will be re-rendered.

**dimensions immediately available**

Other answers here require the user to trigger the `resize` event before dimensions can be accessed. Some have attempted to mitigate the issue using a manual call inside `useEffect`, however these solutions fail in React 18. That is **not** the case for this solution using `useSyncExternalState`. Enjoy immediate access to the dimensions on the first render!

**typescript**

Here's `useDimensions` hook for typescript users -

```
import { RefObject, useMemo, useSyncExternalStore } from "react"

function subscribe(callback: (e: Event) => void) {
  window.addEventListener("resize", callback)
  return () => {
    window.removeEventListener("resize", callback)
  }
}

function useDimensions(ref: RefObject<HTMLElement>) {
  const dimensions = useSyncExternalStore(
    subscribe,
    () => JSON.stringify({
      width: ref.current?.offsetWidth ?? 0,
      height: ref.current?.offsetHeight ?? 0,
    })
  )
  return useMemo(() => JSON.parse(dimensions), [dimensions])
}

export { useDimensions }
```

Comment: Can this be done with an SVG element - for example, an SVGTextElement? Perhaps it could be generalized in TypeScript to specify the element type instead of hard-coding <HTMLElement>?

Answer (score 7):

Use this solution if all you need is exactly the title of this question: the width of a react element.

Complementing on Christopher's comment:
You can use the 'react-use' library to do this. It also listens when the browser resizes. For reference: https://github.com/streamich/react-use/blob/master/docs/useMeasure.md

```
import React from 'react';

import { useMeasure } from 'react-use'; // or just 'react-use-measure'

const sampleView = () => {
 const [ref, { width }] = useMeasure<HTMLDivElement>();
 console.log('Current width of element', width);
 return <div ref={ref}></div>;
};

export default sampleView;
```

Comment: Or https://github.com/pmndrs/react-use-measure if you need only `useMeasure`.

Answer (score 4):

This could be handled perhaps in a simpler way by using **callback refs**.

React allows you to pass a function into a ref, which returns the underlying DOM element or component node. See: https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#callback-refs

```
const MyComponent = () => {
    const myRef = node => console.log(node ? node.innerText : 'NULL!');
    return <div ref={myRef}>Hello World</div>;
 }
```

This function gets fired whenever the underlying node is changed. It will be null in-between updates, so we need to check for this. Example:

```
const MyComponent = () => {
    const [time, setTime] = React.useState(123);
    const myRef = node => console.log(node ? node.innerText : 'NULL!');
    setTimeout(() => setTime(time+1), 1000);
    return <div ref={myRef}>Hello World {time}</div>;
}
/*** Console output: 
 Hello World 123
 NULL!
 Hello World 124
 NULL!
...etc
***/
```

While this does't handle resizing as such (we would still need a resize listener to handle the user resizing the window) I'm not sure that is what the OP was asking for. And this version will handle the node resizing due to an update.

So here is a custom hook based on this idea:

```
export const useClientRect = () => {
    const [rect, setRect] = useState({width:0, height:0});
    const ref = useCallback(node => {
        if (node !== null) {
            const { width, height } = node.getBoundingClientRect();
            setRect({ width, height });
        }
    }, []);
    return [rect, ref];
};
```

The above is based on https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-can-i-measure-a-dom-node

Note the hook *returns* a ref callback, instead of being *passed* a ref. And we employ *useCallback* to avoid re-creating a new ref function each time; not vital, but considered good practice.

Usage is like this (based on Marco Antônio's example):

```
const MyComponent = ({children}) => {
  const [rect, myRef] = useClientRect();
  const { width, height } = rect;

  return (
    <div ref={myRef}>
      <p>width: {width}px</p>
      <p>height: {height}px</p>
      {children}
    <div/>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 4):

React Hook:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect,useRef } from 'react';
...
const table1ref = useRef(null);
const [table1Size, table1SizeSet] = useState({
  width: undefined,
  height: undefined,
});

useEffect(() => {
    function handleResize() {
      table1SizeSet({
        width: table1ref.current.offsetWidth,
        height: table1ref.current.offsetHeight,
      });
    }
    window.addEventListener("resize", handleResize);
    handleResize();
    return () => window.removeEventListener("resize", handleResize);        
  }, [ ]);
...
<div  ref={table1ref}>
```

And call :

```
{table1Size.width}
```

When you want to use.

Answer (score 4):

There is a library, [use-resize-observer](https://github.com/ZeeCoder/use-resize-observer), giving you a hook built around [ResizeObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ResizeObserver).

```
import React from "react";
import useResizeObserver from "use-resize-observer";

const App = () => {
  const { ref, width, height } = useResizeObserver<HTMLDivElement>();

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="instructions">Try resizing this div!</div>
      <div ref={ref} className="box">
        {width}x{height}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 3):

A good practice is listening for resize events to prevent resize on render or even a user window resize that can bug your application.

```
const MyComponent = ()=> {
  const myRef = useRef(null)

  const [myComponenetWidth, setMyComponentWidth] = useState('')

  const handleResize = ()=>{ 
    setMyComponentWidth(myRef.current.offsetWidth)
  }

  useEffect(() =>{
    if(myRef.current)
      myRef.current.addEventListener('resize', handleResize)

    return ()=> {
     myRef.current.removeEventListener('resize', handleResize)
    }
  }, [myRef])

  return (
  <div ref={MyRef}>Hello</div>
  )
}
```

Comment: You have to attach the resize event listener to the window I think: developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/resize_event

Comment: No you have to add this to the ref of the component that you want to know the width. Not every resize on the window, will cause the component to resize as well

Answer (score 1):

**custom hook**

```
import { useCallback, useState } from "react";

const useContainerDimensions = () => {
  const [size, setRect] = useState(null);
  const ref = useCallback(node => {
    if (node !== null) {
      setRect(node.getBoundingClientRect());
    }
  }, []);
  return [size, ref];
}
export default useContainerDimensions;
```

**and then you can use it like**

```
const [size, ref] = useContainerDimensions();

return (
 <Text ellipsis style={{maxWidth: size?.width}}>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod 
  tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim 
  veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea 
  commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate 
  velit esse cillum dolore
 </Text>
)
```

Comment: the usage example is incomplete.`ref` is a callback that must be called with an element reference otherwise `size` will be `null`.

Answer (score 1):

here is a example in react
to get the
width of the a element both at page render as well when page is resized

```
import { useLayoutEffect, useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react'
    const MyComponent = ()=> {    
        const ref = useRef(null)
            const [divWidth, setDivWidth] = useState('')
            const handleResize = () => {
                setDivWidth(ref.current.offsetWidth)
            }
            useEffect(() => {
                if (ref.current) window.addEventListener('resize', 
           handleResize)
        
                return () => {
                    window.removeEventListener('resize', handleResize)
                }
            }, [ref])
        
            useLayoutEffect(() => {
                setDivWidth(ref.current.offsetWidth)
            }, [])
        
        return (
             <div ref={ref} className="warper">
                <div style={{ minWidth: divWidth }}>
                    hello
                </div>
             </div>
        )
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const MyComponent = () => {
  const [offsetWidth, setOffsetWidth] = useState(0)
  return <div ref={r=>{r !== null && setOffsetWidth(r.offsetWidth)}}>Hello</div>
};
```

safer than useRef because it will rerender when `div` is mounted