# How to get the height of a react.element

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I'm dynamically rendering a list of `Symbol(react.element)` by mapping into an array and placing each of its elements HTML tags. My question is therefore: how can I get the height of each of the rendered `Symbol(react.element)`? This seems not to be in the `Symbol(react.element)`'s object.

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43817118/how-to-get-the-width-of-a-react-element

Comment: Have you tried getting `.offsetHeight` of the element? Here is [how to access element in modern react](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38093981/8122487). Also, what do you make symbols of your elements for?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
 class MyComponent extends Component {
      constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.myDiv = React.createRef()
      }

      componentDidMount () {
        console.log(this.myDiv.current.offsetHeight)
      }

      render () {
        return (
          <div ref={this.myDiv}>element</div>
        )
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 10):

Actually, if you are using Functional Components, would be better to isolate this resize logic in a **custom hook** instead of leave it inside the component. You can create a custom hook like this:

```
const useResize = (myRef) => {
  const [width, setWidth] = useState(0)
  const [height, setHeight] = useState(0)

  const handleResize = () => {
    setWidth(myRef.current.offsetWidth)
    setHeight(myRef.current.offsetHeight)
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    myRef.current && myRef.current.addEventListener('resize', handleResize)

    return () => {
      myRef.current.removeEventListener('resize', handleResize)
    }
  }, [myRef])

  return { width, height }
}
```

and then you can use it like:

```
const MyComponent = () => {
  const componentRef = useRef()
  const { width, height } = useResize(componentRef)

  return (
    <div ref={componentRef}>
      <p>width: {width}px</p>
      <p>height: {height}px</p>
    <div/>
  )
}
```

Comment: myRef is undefined :

Comment: @AlainIb change it to componentRef =))

Comment: You are right, thanks for updating it @Duy Huynh

Answer (score 2):

*A modified version of Marcos answer.*

I've placed a rendering bool to make sure all data is rendered before placing the height and width. This is to be sure that the height is calculated with all required elements in place instead of risking receiving an incorrect height and width.

*useResize hook placed in a separate folder:*

```
import { useState, useEffect, useCallback } from 'react';

export const useResize = (myRef: React.MutableRefObject<any>, rendering: boolean) => {
    const [width, setWidth] = useState(0);
    const [height, setHeight] = useState(0);

    const handleResize = useCallback(() => {
        setWidth(myRef.current.offsetWidth);
        setHeight(myRef.current.offsetHeight);
    }, [myRef]);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (!rendering) {
            myRef.current && myRef.current.addEventListener('resize', 
            handleResize(), { once: true });
        }
    }, [myRef, handleResize, rendering]);

    return { width, height };
```

Example of usage:

```
const MyComponent = ({ A, B }) => {

  // A and B is data that is required in component

  const componentRef = useRef()
  const { width, height } = useResize(componentRef, !A || !B)

  if (!A || !B) return;

  return (
    <div ref={componentRef}>
      <p>{A} {width}px</p>
      <p>{B} {height}px</p>
    <div/>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

const componentRef = useRef(**null**)
and div ref={**componentRef**}