# How to truncate a overflowed text in a react element with middle ellipsis?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to react. so any help is greatly appreciated. I have a react table in which one of the columns holds the name of each row. I have names like "entry", "entry (1)", ... "entry (n)"
I want to be able to deal with the text overflow when the name is long but I want to keep the index of the name, hence can't use css (text-overflow:"ellipses"

is there a way that I could have "ent... (n)"?

Comment: Check the width of the `<td>` element (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43817118/how-to-get-the-width-of-a-react-element), and if it too long - truncate it, letter by letter in a loop, until it's in the correct width.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve that with a combination of flexbox and `position: absolute`. The absolute position prevents the div from effecting the width of the table column, while filling the `td`'s full width. The flexbox limits the text area width, which enables the appearance of ellipsis:

```js
const Entry = ({ children, index }) => (
  <div className="entry">
    <div className="entry__inner">
      <span className="entry__text">{children}</span>
      <span className="entry__index">({index})</span>
    </div>
  </div>
);

const Demo = ({ entries }) => (
  <table>
    <thead>
      <th>Name</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      {entries.map((text, index) => (
        <tr key={index}>
          <td>
            <Entry index={index}>{text}</Entry>
          </td>
        </tr>
      ))}
    </tbody>
  </table>
);

const entries = ['entry', 'long entry', 'long long entry'];

ReactDOM.render(
  <Demo entries={entries} />,
  demo
);
```

```css
td {
  width: 5.5em;
}

.entry {
  position: relative;
  height: 1em;
}

.entry__inner {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.entry__text {
  flex: 1;
  margin-right: 0.5em;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.entry__index {
  text-align: right();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="demo"></div>
```