# current is always null when using React.createRef

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ref

I was trying to do [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43817118/how-to-get-the-width-of-a-react-element).

I must be missing something, but I don't understand why `current` is always `null` in this example.

```
class App extends React.PureComponent {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.test = React.createRef();
  }
  render() {
    return <div className="App">current value : {this.test.current + ""}</div>;
  }
}
```

You can check my test case [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/q4l6nzloyq)

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Because you forgot to assign the ref to some dom element. You are only creating it.

Write it like this:

```
class App extends React.PureComponent {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.test = React.createRef();
  }

  handleClick = () => alert(this.test.current.value)

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <input ref={this.test} />
        <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Get Value</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

[Working Example.](https://codesandbox.io/s/vigilant-payne-m4ejg)

Comment: I realize this was answered a while ago, but the working example you provided says "current value : null". Shouldn't it give a value?

Comment: Why do we need to assign the ref in the constructor? In my case i did not have a constructor. initialized the ref, however it was coming back as null.

Answer (score 18):

I know this is not the solution to OP's problem but for those who are coming from google search, one of the ways the ref.current can be null is that if the component on which the ref is being attached is a connected component. Like with react-redux connect or withRouter. For react-redux the solution is to pass forwardRef:true in the fourth option to connect.

Answer (score 13):

React.createRef() is asynchronous so if you try to access the ref in componentDidMount, it will return null and later return the properties of the component in which you are referencing.

```
componentDidMount(): void {
      if (this.viewShot && this.viewShot.current) {
          this.viewShot.current.capture().then((uri) => {
        console.log('do something with ', uri);
          });
      }
  }
```

This is the right way to use the React.createRef() in this context.

Comment: You're totally wrong! React updates all DOM and refs before componentDidMount fires.  
What is capture method? It doesn't exist both for 'current' element as ref instance and nor for input element
I just can't figure out why there's so much positive review

PS: Accepted answer correct!

Answer (score 9):

This may happen in the following circumstances:

- You have forgotten to pass your *ref* to the component i.e `this.test` from the question.

> `<Component ref={this.test} />`

- You are using **Redux** in which the component to which *ref* props is passed is wrapped by `connect` method and hence `this.test.current` would return *null* as it points to the Redux wrapper, to make this kind of component work make `forwardRef: true`

> i.e: `connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps, null, {forwardRef: true})(Component)`

- If you are using `withRouter` and `connect` together then instead of *one* here you are having *two* *wrappers* and `this.test.current` would obviously return *null*, to overcome this make sure `withRouter` wraps `connect`

> `withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps, null, {forwardRef: true})(Component))`

and then

> `<Component wrappedComponentRef={ref => this.test = ref} />`

`wrappedComponentRef` is a prop used to make the wrapped component available just as `forwardRef: true`, you can find it in docs [here](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/withRouter/wrappedcomponentref-func)

Comment: I am using withTranslation to connect my class component. Cannot pass  {forwardRef: true} this one. do you have any idea how can I fix it?

Comment: Super nice to have these things all in one answer

Answer (score 8):

You're missing the `ref={this.test}` prop.

```
return (
  <div className="App" ref={this.test}>
    current value : {this.test.current + ""}
  </div>
);
```

Answer (score 3):

In version 17.0.2 of React, refs and it being asynchronous got changed. Code like this stopped working properly after the update:

```js
import {useRef} from 'react';
import './kind.css'

const Kind = ({prop}) => {

    // defining the ref
    const kindRef = useRef('')
    
    // print the ref to the console
    console.log(kindRef)


    return (
    <div ref={kindRef} className="kind-container" >
        <div className="kind" data-kind='drink'>Drink</div>
        <div className="kind" data-kind='sweet'>Sweet</div>
        <div className="kind" data-kind='lorem'>lorem</div>
        <div className="kind" data-kind='ipsum'>ipsum</div>
        <div className="kind" data-kind='ipsum' >food</div>
    </div>
    );
}

export default Kind;
```

After initializing the ref it takes sometime to assign it to the dom. Javascript, being a synchronous language, doesn't wait for the ref to initialize and skips straight to the log.

To fix this we will need to use `useEffect` like this

```js
import { useRef, useEffect} from 'react';
import './kind.css'

const Kind = ({prop}) => {

    // defining the ref
    const kindRef = useRef('')
    
    // using 'useEffect' will help us to do what ever you want to your ref varaible,
    // by waiting to letting the elements to mount:'mount means after the elements get inserted in the page' and then do what you want the ref
    useEffect(()=>{

        // print the ref to the console
        console.log(kindRef)        

    })


    return (
    <div ref={kindRef} className="kind-container" >
        <div className="kind" data-kind='drink'>Drink</div>
        <div className="kind" data-kind='sweet'>Sweet</div>
        <div className="kind" data-kind='lorem'>lorem</div>
        <div className="kind" data-kind='ipsum'>ipsum</div>
        <div className="kind" data-kind='ipsum' >food</div>
    </div>
    );
}

export default Kind;
```

`useEffect` waits to the ref to be assigned to the DOM element and then runs the function assigned to it.

Comment: React documentation would encourage you to use `useLayoutEffect` in this specific case. Also, it's probably safer to log `kindRef.current`, as the console logs are not static. Finally, It might be a good practice to always specify the dependency array in hooks like useEffect

Comment: As you noticed, I edited your question to better fit the [answering guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Your original answer included several grammar mistakes. You also specifically asked for upvotes, which is something that is also against the rules. Finally, you uselessly signed your name in a codeblock. Your username is displayed at the bottom right corner of your answer (above the comments). Please do not rollback your answer to it's original version; I have made changes that are keeping your answer aligned to the guidelines and preventing it from being removed.

Comment: Thanks bro , I were on hurry

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the `ref` in `useCallback` (or another hook), remember to add the `ref` to the dependencies:

```
const doSomething = useCallback(() => {
 ref.current?.doIt();
}, [ref]);
```

Comment: I was racking my brain for 5 hours and I just needed to get this done. Thank you very much. Reports from a BackEnd developer trying to program React.

Answer (score -2):

```html
<div ref={this.test}>
```

You have to assign `ref` prop to your DOM element.
In this case you have to assign ref to div element

Comment: What is this response adding to the selected answer?