# How to get a width of a div when using ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

First of all I'm aver that someone already asked this question ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43817118/how-to-get-the-width-of-a-react-element)) but I don't exactly know how to use the answer in my project.

My problem:

I have a div with an id of **square**. I want to get the width of this element, and this is my code:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import './login.css';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';

//pic imports
//...
/pic imports end

function Login() {
  const pics_slide_ref = React.createRef();

  const [width, setWidth] = 0;

  useEffect(() => {
    if (pics_slide_ref.current) {
      setWidth(pics_slide_ref.current.getBoundingClientRect().width);
      console.log(width);
    }
  }, [])



  var choosenProfile = 'pic_1';
  function profileChoosen(id) {
    document.getElementById(choosenProfile).classList.remove('choosen');
    choosenProfile = id;
    document.getElementById(choosenProfile).classList.add('choosen');
  }

  return (
    <div className="login">
      <div className="login-container">
        <input placeholder="Your Email..." />
        <input placeholder="Your Username..." />
        <input placeholder="Your password..." />
        <div className="loged-out">
          <button className="sign-in">Sign in</button>
          <button className="sign-up">Sign up</button>
        </div>
        <div className="loged-in">
          <button className="sign-out">Sign out</button>
        </div>


      </div>

      <div className="pic-container">
        <div className="pic-choos">
          <span>Choose a profile pic</span>
        </div>
        <div className="pics">
          <div className="pics-compact">
            <span>&#60;</span>
            <div ref={pics_slide_ref} id="pics-slide-space" className="pics-slide-space">
              <div id="pics-slide-1" className="pics-slide-1">
                <img src={pic_1} alt="#" id="pic_1" onClick={() => profileChoosen('pic_1')} />
                <img src={pic_2} alt="#" id="pic_2" onClick={() => profileChoosen('pic_2')} />
                <img src={pic_3} alt="#" id="pic_3" onClick={() => profileChoosen('pic_3')} />
                <img src={pic_4} alt="#" id="pic_4" onClick={() => profileChoosen('pic_4')} />
                <img src={pic_5} alt="#" id="pic_5" onClick={() => profileChoosen('pic_5')} />
                <img src={pic_6} alt="#" id="pic_6" onClick={() => profileChoosen('pic_6')} />
                <img src={pic_7} alt="#" id="pic_7" onClick={() => profileChoosen('pic_7')} />
                <img src={pic_8} alt="#" id="pic_8" onClick={() => profileChoosen('pic_8')} />
                <img src={pic_9} alt="#" id="pic_9" onClick={() => profileChoosen('pic_9')} />
                <img src={pic_10} alt="#" id="pic_10" onClick={() => profileChoosen('pic_10')} />

              </div>
            </div>
            <span>&#62;</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Login;
```

Unfortunately it does not work. Is there a simple way of getting the width? 
If there isn't can someone explain me in details that how to do it?

Comment: can you provide more code

Comment: What part should I post?

Comment: Your react component that has the square.

Comment: Take a look at react refs and ref callbacks: https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#callback-refs

Comment: Hi @BudaÖrs see my solution below with working codesandbox. Let me know if that helps :)

Comment: You have `const [width, setWidth] = 0`. Use `useState(0)`, not just 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You actually need to assign the `ref` to the div. Use the `ref` in combination with `useState()` and `useEffect()`. We integrate `useEffect()` because it runs right after the first render of the component, thus ensuring that the div and hence ref is valid.

Then we get the width of the div and store it in `state` so you can use it in your mark-up.

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';

function SquareHolder() {
    const [width, setWidth] = useState(0)
    const square_ref = React.createRef();

    useEffect(() => {
       if(square_ref.current){
          setWidth(square_ref.current.getBoundingClientRect().width)
       }
    }, [])


    return (
        <div className="square" ref={square_ref}>
            The width is: {width}
        </div>
    );
}

export default SquareHolder;
```

See working sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-sara-fp319

Comment: I tried it, and i got: TypeError: arr[Symbol.iterator] is not a function :((

Comment: @BudaÖrs there's nothing referencing arr[] in the code you posted. :(. You need to give us more context.

Comment: I didn't know I have an arr[] either :(

Comment: @BudaÖrs my bad, the problem was here. Just use this line  `const [width, setWidth] = useState(0)`;   I was missing the useState() call in my original code.

Comment: Thank you! This time it did not collapsed :))

Comment: At this line 

setWidth(pics_slide_ref.current.getBoundingClientRect().width);
      console.log(width);

When I console.log the with it writes 0 on the console.

Comment: I know whats the problem

Comment: The useEffect's 2 argument is empty. It should be [width]

Comment: Thank you for your help and patient :))

Comment: Great :). I'm glad that was helpful to you. @BudaÖrs

Answer (score 4):

You can use `ref` and `getBoundingClientRect()` to get width of any element.

Define a `ref` in your constructor:

```
this.myRef = React.createRef()
```

Then, attach it to your component.

```
<YourComponent ref={this.myref} />
```

Then, call `getBoundingClientRect()` like this:

```
myref.current.getBoundingClientRect().width
```

Comment: I try it... :))

Comment: I get: TypeError: Cannot read property 'getBoundingClientRect' of null

Comment: Component should be mounted before you call it. From where are you invoking the function? Try calling from `componentDidMount`, for example. @BudaÖrs

Comment: @BudaÖrs Attach the `ref` to your component. See second step in my answer :)

Comment: I have a messier version of this example I tried to simplify what I'm doing. There I did add the ref. And it still did't work. Sorry for being so dumb :(

Comment: I am glad I could help! @BudaÖrs