# How can I get a width of html element in React JS?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I need to get a width of html element, using React JS. When I do `console.log(this.widthPromoLine)` in `componentDidMount()`, it works, but when I do `this.setState({moveContent: this.widthPromoLine})`, it doesn't.

```js
import React from 'react'
import './index.css'

class Promo extends React.Component {


    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            moveContent: 0
        }
    }
    
    componentDidMount(){
        this.setState({moveContent: this.widthPromoLine})
    }
    
    render(){
      return <div 
                className="promo-content" 
                ref={promoLine => this.widthPromoLine = promoLine.clientWidth}> 
             </div>
    }


}
```

```css
.promo-content {
  width: 1870px;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the width of a react element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43817118/how-to-get-the-width-of-a-react-elementt)

Answer (score 4):

Access the `clientWidth` after the ref has been assigned to the variable `this.widthPromoLine` in `componentDidMount` and then set it like below. Also `setState` is async, so you need to do anything after the state has been updated in the callback of `setState`.

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

class Promo extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      moveContent: 0
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({ moveContent: this.widthPromoLine.clientWidth }, () => {
      console.log(this.state);
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div
        className="promo-content"
        ref={promoLine => (this.widthPromoLine = promoLine)}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Hope this helps !

Answer (score 1):

You can get the width of content using it classname as follow.

```
let width = document.querySelector(".promo-content").offsetWidth;
```

And after that update the state,

```
this.setState({moveContent: width})
```