# In react, how can I determine the width of a container before rendering a child image?

Tags: reactjs

I have an image which I want to absolute position within a parent div, but I don't know the size of the parent div until it renders.

In React, how can I get the width of the container before rendering the image?

Any hack solution is allowed as long as it works.

Bonus for having it respond to window size changes.

Comment: See [How to get the width of a react element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43817118/how-to-get-the-width-of-a-react-element)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a ref to get the div element, and then check its size in an effect. You'll probably set state at that point, thus rendering again now that you know the size.

```
const Example = () => {
  const [width, setWidth] = useState(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    setWidth(containerRef.current.clientWidth);
  }, []);

  const containerRef = useRef(null);

  return (
    <div ref={containerRef}>
      {width !== null && (
        // render an image, using the width however you need to
      )}
    </div>
  )
}
```

Depending on what you're doing with this width, you may see a flicker due to it rendering once without the image, and once with. If that's the case, you can eliminate the flicker by switching from `useEffect` to `useLayoutEffect`. This will make the 2nd render be synchronous, and thus the user will not get a chance to see the 1st render.

> Bonus for having it respond to window size changes.

You can listen to window resize like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const handleResize = () => {
    setWidth(containerRef.current.clientWidth);
  }

  window.addEventListener('resize', handleResize);

  return () => window.removeEventListener('resize', handleResize);
}, []);
```

Comment: one extra question: what if my image is in a table and the cells resize? Is there a simple way to listen/update based on that?